# ChefSpec test breaking with rvm include

Tags: rvm, chef-infra, chefspec

So I'm trying to write a unit test (via ChefSpec) for one of my Chef recipes but I am getting some odd behaviour.

My recipe in question is including the rvm::system_install recipe and apparently this is causing issues with ChefSpec:

```
Failures:

1) theoracle::prereqs installs libyaml libyaml-devel sqlite-devel
 Failure/Error: let(:chef_run) { ChefSpec::Runner.new.converge('theoracle::prereqs')}
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
 # /Users/jdoe/workspace/cookbooks/rvm/libraries/chef_rvm_recipe_helpers.rb:44:in `install_pkg_prereqs'
 # /Users/jdoe/workspace/cookbooks/rvm/recipes/system_install.rb:29:in `from_file'
 # ./recipes/prereqs.rb:22:in `from_file'
 # ./spec/unit/recipes/prereqs_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/unit/recipes/prereqs_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The offending code segment:

```
/Users/jdoe/workspace/cookbooks/rvm/libraries/chef_rvm_recipe_helpers.rb:

41:        def install_pkg_prereqs(install_now = node.recipe?("rvm::gem_package"))
42:          return if mac_with_no_homebrew
43:
44>>         node[:rvm][:install_pkgs].each do |pkg|
45:            p = package pkg do
```

This is how my test looks like:

```rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'theoracle::prereqs' do
  let(:chef_run) { ChefSpec::Runner.new.converge('theoracle::prereqs')}

  it 'installs libyaml libyaml-devel sqlite-devel' do
    %W( libyaml libyaml-devel sqlite-devel ).each do |pkg|
      expect(chef_run).to_install_package(pkg)
    end
  end
end
```

This is the `theoracle::prereqs` recipe (part of it):

```rb
%W( libyaml libyaml-devel sqlite-devel ).each do |pkg|
  package pkg do
    action :install
  end
end

include_recipe 'rvm::system_install'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what is happening:

```rb
node[:rvm][:install_pkgs]
```

is returning `nil`. Thus you are calling `nil.each` and getting the exception. Unfortunately there are a number of possibilities of why that attribute could be `nil`.

### Dependency

In your `theoracle` cookbook, have you added a dependency on the `rvm` cookbook in your `metadata.rb`?

```rb
depends 'rvm'
```

Without this line, Chef will not load the RVM cookbook (and thus not load its attributes), causing the `install_pkgs` attribute to be `nil`.

### Default Attribute (most likely)

If you [look at the code for determining the value of that attribute](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rvm/blob/dd58087e7399097a9b9df4e2e7235908aace2afd/attributes/default.rb#L65-L78) in the `chef-rvm` cookbook, you can see that `node[:rvm][:install_pkgs]` is only set under the following conditions:

```rb
case platform
when "redhat","centos","fedora","scientific","amazon"
  node.set['rvm']['install_pkgs']   = %w{sed grep tar gzip bzip2 bash curl git}
  default['rvm']['user_home_root']  = '/home'
when "debian","ubuntu","suse"
  node.set['rvm']['install_pkgs']   = %w{sed grep tar gzip bzip2 bash curl git-core}
  default['rvm']['user_home_root']  = '/home'
when "gentoo"
  node.set['rvm']['install_pkgs']   = %w{git}
  default['rvm']['user_home_root']  = '/home'
when "mac_os_x", "mac_os_x_server"
  node.set['rvm']['install_pkgs']   = %w{git}
  default['rvm']['user_home_root']  = '/Users'
end
```

In the case of ChefSpec, all Ohai data (which is what sets the `platform` key), is mocked to allow control over this behavior. **Most likely**, ChefSpec is reporting its platform as `chefspec`, and since that `case` statement has no default block, the attribute is `nil`.

To fix this issue, tell ChefSpec to behave like a particular OS:

```rb
ChefSpec::Runner.new(platform: 'ubuntu', version: '12.04')
```

Or manually set the attribute in your test:

```rb
let(:chef_run) do
  ChefSpec::Runner.new do |node|
    node.set['rvm']['install_pkgs'] = %w(whatever)
  end.converge(described_recipe)
end
```

Comment: I get a TypeError:can't convert Array into String on the following line: `vo_pass = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load(data_bag, node[:theoracle][:user_databag_item], secret)`. I've tried setting the attributes during the chefspec converge (although in this case that shouldn't be required). Does that ring a bell? The attributes in question are all string literals.

Comment: @keftes that sounds like a completely different question. Please open a new question.

Comment: Nope, got it, nevermind. Your documentation is pretty clear about mocking encrypted data bags. Thanks.